# Are [(ngModel)] bindings always strings?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Consider a radiobutton HTML element in an angular application,

```
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="approvedeny" value="true" [(ngModel)]=_approvedOrDenied>
      Approve
    </label>
  </div>
```

On our component, the `_approvedOrDenied` property is declared as a boolean.

```
@Component({   
export class ApprovalsComponent implements OnInit {
  _approvedOrDenied: boolean;
```

However, when stepping through the clientside code, this is being set to a string.  There's no casts in my code that would do this, seems like angular is doing it automatically.

[image]

Are all databound properties returned as strings in angular?  And if so, what is the point of declaring the type `_approvedOrDenied: boolean` in typescript?

Comment: I guess it's because of `value="true"` m try instead `[value]="true"`

Comment: official documentation says that model is a `any` type https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it isn't always a string. And by the way, that's the first time I see a tag without quotes !

When you make a compoment with an input like this

```
<app-my-component firstVariable="hello world"></app-my-component>
```

Then it's a string. You can't even give a variable in this case, the input will have the variable's name as value.

But if you do

```
<app-my-component [firstVariable]="hello world"></app-my-component>
```

Then it won't work. Because here, you're supposed to give a variable. To make it work, use this

```
<app-my-component [firstVariable]="'Hello world'"></app-my-component>
```

Now, you're giving something like an "anonymous variable" : you use quotes, so Angular understands it's a string.

In your case, you use a radio button. Radio buttons are part of radio button groups, and each of them have **string values**. So even if you write true, that doesn't mean it's a boolean ! If you want to give it a boolean, you will have to use

```
[value]="true"
```

I hope I helped !

Comment: Thank you, yes this worked for me.  I will read through again and try to digest what you're saying.  

What do you mean "this is the first time I've seen a tag without quotes"?  Do you mean this line: `[(ngModel)]=_approvedOrDenied` (as opposed to `"_approvedOrDenied"`)

Comment: yes that's what I meant, I've never not used quotes, so it's a bit startling for me, but I'm glad to learn it works this way ! I'll save 2 keystrokes from now on :p

Comment: Caveat: it *seems* to work.  I had quotes intiially, but in the process of debugging here, I removed them.  This is not to say that I didn't break something else as a result :)  But the code compiles and runs so...

Comment: So I guess once my code is browser side, the fact that typescript was used to enforce a `boolean` variable type is hogwash?

Comment: My guess is that Typescript is able to make the difference between a string and a boolean by testing the type of the values you send, thus he doesn't really "enforce" them, but rather handles them with the type you wanted them to have. But I'm not an expert, so don't take it as the only true answer !

Comment: And after all, you can parse a string "true" to boolean, and number 1 to boolean too, so it shouldn't be a problem once built !

Answer (score 0):

Remove `value="true"` from the html and it should work

Comment: So I did this and the radio button doesn't work correctly.  IE I can't click on the approve button, it's stuck on deny.